# Relaxing continuous derivatives to differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

According to Wikipedia, in Clairaut's theorem we can relax the assumption of continuous second derivatives to differentiable first derivatives.

Since Clairaut's theorem can be proved with Green's theorem, can we also relax the assumption there?

If not, why can we do it for Clairaut's theorem? What is the intuitive difference between the two assumptions?